# Simulation of Simulink Model for Crude Oil Distillation Unit

Tags: model, simulation

***strong text***I have been able to build the simulink model for the Mathematically but am having it difficult to simulate the model.
[nth stage mode of the CDU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOgQE.jpg)

The Mathematical Model of the simulink model is:
dMn*xn/dt = L(n+1)*x(n+1) - Ln*xn + V(n-1)*y(n-1) - Vn*yn

Comment: I am now able to build the simulink model and simulate most part of the CDU.

Answer (score 0):

I am now able to build the simulink model and simulate most part of the CDU